# How to show that a given set is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

OK I just want to be sure I have done this correctly.

Given: $R^3$, are the following sets subspaces?

(a) $W_1$ = {($a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$) $\in R^3: a_1 = 3a_2$ and $a_3 = -a_2$

Since the set you get when you plug in the values to the set you get (3$a_2$,$a_2$,$-a_2$), and that is the same as $a_2$(3,1,-1). Which means that the set is closed under addition since the vector you want is a linear combination -- it can be expressed as a multiple of (3, -1, 1). It's also closed under multiplication since any arbitrary $a_2$ I plug in is still in $R^3$. So, the addition and multiplication are all defined in the relevant vector space. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

However what you did seems right, it would be nice verifying the definition of a subspace. Of course $0=0~(3,1,-1)\in W$ and if we took $v=(a_1,a_2,a_3),w=(b_1,b_2,b_3)\in W$ then we would see $$\alpha v+\beta w\in W$$ as well wherein $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$. It can be seen just by doing some manipulation.

Comment: Yaaay! thanks, I have been sort of freaked a bit in this linear algebra class... I seem ok with the computations but the proofs are already sort of hard.

Comment: @Jesse *Always* remember to check whether the set contains $0$. The reason is to verify that the set is not empty. If it were empty, closure under addition and multiplication would be vacuously true. So you *must* check that it is nonempty which is usually done by checking whether $0$ is in the set.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply write:
$$W_1 = \{(a_1,a_2,a_3) \in \mathbb R^3: a_1 = 3a_2\quad\text{ and}\quad a_3 = -a_2\}=\mathrm{span}((3,1,-1))$$
so $W_1$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.